# Javascript cookie opt out - how do I verify that it works?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am a noob in javascript, but I need an opt-out-function for cookies (dataprivacy reasons). I googled and found this cookie-opt-out-script on https://cookieconsent.insites.com/download/ and inserted the callback hock
https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/disabling-cookies/

But I am not sure if everything is correct, I doubt that it is working, because the browser still shows me cookies. How can I make sure it does work?

Thanks for your help!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
"palette": {
"popup": {
  "background": "#f1f1f1",
  "text": "#32394b"
},
"button": {
  "background": "transparent",
  "text": "#32394b",
  "border": "#e45468",
}
},
"position": "top",
"static": false,
"type": "opt-out",
onInitialise: function (status) {
var type = this.options.type;
var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
// enable cookies
}
if (type == 'opt-out' && !didConsent) {
// disable cookies
}
},

onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
var type = this.options.type;
var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
// enable cookies
}
if (type == 'opt-out' && !didConsent) {
// disable cookies
}
},

onRevokeChoice: function() {
var type = this.options.type;
if (type == 'opt-in') {
// disable cookies
}
if (type == 'opt-out') {
// enable cookies
}
},
})});

</script>
```

Comment: The script does nothing regarding cookies on its own; it's just shows the message and handles the click. Where it says `// disable cookies` you need to for instance set a variable like `cookies_allowed = false;`. Later, when other code of yours wants to set a cookie, you need to check the variable first. If you are using scripts that generate cookies, you have to manually alter them.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! I changed it as you said, but when I press decline I still don't see the exeption (of allowing every cookie) in the settings, e.g. in firefox. Is this normal? How can I check if it works without only checking the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "settings" here; this script does nothing to the browser, at all. It does not switch the Firefox tab into some "cookieless" mode or something. It really doesn't do anything except display a box and provide code to handle clicks on the accept / decline options. Everything else has to be implemented manually. I don't know what you mean by "without only checking the code". Are you asking how to look at the cookies that a website creates?

Comment: How do I implement that manually? I made the changes you said: `if (type == 'opt-in') {
// disable cookies
}
if (type == 'opt-out') {
// enable cookies
}` I know how to check what cookies are created, but when you opt out cookies (lets assume it would work), how would I see it in the browser settings/administration of cookies etc.? Would they just disappear, would it create an "exception" so that no cookies where taken by the browser or what is the regular effect of the opt-out regarding the browser settings? I hope you understand me now :)

Comment: For the third time: the browser itself is **NOT** affected in **ANY WAY**. Nothing will disappear. *YOU* have to make sure that your website and no script it uses creates any cookies, if the visitor chose to opt-out. Let me put it this way: you have a park full of trash and you want the trash to go and stay away. Right now, all you have done is put up a "no littering" sign. Obviously, that will not make the trash magically disappear. You have to a) clean up the trash that's already there and b) enforce the no littering rule by preventing people from dropping additional trash. Clear yet...?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9hrcfxay/ You cannot use this as-is, it's just supposed to show what needs to be done in addition to including the script you already have.